# fix the content in ScrolledText Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In general ScrolledText works like html textfield, we have readonly option to make the text field as non-editable, is there any command for make the ScolledText portion as non-editable.

Thank you.

Comment: What research have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: problem solved, I have used **obj.config(state='disabled')** to make a non-editable ScrolledText.

Answer (score -1):

according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/scrolledtext.html#module-ScrolledText) the constructor is effectively the same as the text field. so if you can render a text field readonly then you can use the same method on a scrolledtext field